# How to play wave data from UDP stream (c#)

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, udp, audio-streaming

I want to create an app, which will receive wave data via network through UDP broadcast. How can I set up to play received wave data using MSDN components (without any Third-party lib or software). I have tried to find with Google , but so far haven't any succeed. Any help or hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for UdpClient
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Article on using DirectSound, from DirectX, with C#
http://khason.net/blog/capturing-and-streaming-sound-by-using-directsound-with-c/